# Django: user login system is not working in the same page with user registration

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm new to Django and trying to make a user registration and login system in same HTML page.

 My user registration part is working but login part is not.

 So, my views.py is in the below,

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.get('submit') == 'Kayıt Ol':
            username= request.POST['username']
            email= request.POST['email']
            password= request.POST['password']

            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
               messages.info(request,'Bu kullanıcı adı kullanılıyor')
               return redirect('/')
            elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
               messages.info(request,'Bu email kullanılıyor.')
               return redirect('/')
            else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)
                user.save()
                return redirect('/')
        else:
           return render(request, 'blog/SignPage.html')
    
    elif request.POST.get('submit') == 'Oturum Aç':
            username= request.POST.get('username')
            password= request.POST.get('password')

            user= auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)

            if user is not None:
                auth.signin(request,user)
                redirect('/anasayfa')
            else : 
                messages.info(request,'Yanlış kullanıcı adı veya şifre')
                return redirect('/')

    else:
        return render(request, 'blog/SignPage.html')
```

Also my urls.py is,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='kaydol'),
]
```

Edit: I add my imports.

Comment: What is happening on your login page?

Comment: Nothing happens, neither gives errors, nor users can enter. @BernardoDuarte

Comment: I would use the built-in auth views and just make a custom template with a login and a signup form (based on the built-in auth templates), just add an "action" attribute to each form pointing to the right url, ie. accounts/login or acocunts/signup etc. Easy and secure...

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to say and I don't know how to do that. :( @Chris

Comment: In your virtual environment, in \Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\ there are the default Django (secure...) views and templates that you can copy and use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's an indentation error. Here, check the code below to see if it works.

And you should change `auth.signin` to [`auth.login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login).

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.get('submit') == 'Kayıt Ol':
            username= request.POST['username']
            email= request.POST['email']
            password= request.POST['password']

            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
               messages.info(request,'Bu kullanıcı adı kullanılıyor')
               return redirect('/')
            elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
               messages.info(request,'Bu email kullanılıyor.')
               return redirect('/')
            else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)
                user.save()
                return redirect('/')

        elif request.POST.get('submit') == 'Oturum Aç':
            username= request.POST.get('username')
            password= request.POST.get('password')

            user= auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)

            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request,user)
                return redirect('/anasayfa')
            else : 
                messages.info(request,'Yanlış kullanıcı adı veya şifre')
                return redirect('/')

    else:
        return render(request, 'blog/SignPage.html')
```

Comment: I tried but it gave `module 'django.contrib.auth' has no attribute 'signin' ` error.

Comment: @ilayda I've edited the answer, please check it out ;D

Comment: Now it gave `The view blog.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.` error :( @BernardoDuarte

Comment: @ilayda Sorry, i'm tired XD I've missed the return on `redirect('/anasayfa')`